# Gnus store sent mail in Inbox

Tags: gnus

Is there a way to make Gnus store sent emails in the inbox folder?

I would like to see **all** mail, i.e., received and sent mail, in my mail threads in my inbox.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Gnus Parameters. The one you are looking for is `gcc-self`. I also use that to keep replies in the folder I reply from, not just the inbox.

http://www.gnus.org/manual/gnus_21.html#Group-Parameters

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by sending the email in CC to myself.

Put this in your **.gnus**

```
(setq gnus-posting-styles
  '((".*"
     ("CC" "YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS")
     (address "YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS"))))
```

Every email you send will be send directly to yourself in CC.